# LocationListener InSide AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Hi I am New to android programming and currently developing an application that uses location manager to get user location and place a marker on a map. i am attempting to use AsyncTask to run the LocationListener and Constantly update the marker when the user location has changed.
this is the class i am working on...

```
public class IncidentActivity extends MapActivity{


   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       this.setContentView(R.layout.incidentactivity);

       mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
       mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);   
       mapView.setTraffic(true);


        mapController = mapView.getController();
        String coordinates[] = {"-26.167004","27.965505"};
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
        geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1E6), (int)(lng*1E6));
        mapController.animateTo(geoPoint);
        mapController.setZoom(16);
        mapView.invalidate();

         new MyLocationAsyncTask().execute();

   }



      private class MyLocationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Location, Void> implements LocationListener{
        private  double latLocation;
        private Location l;

        //location management variables to track and maintain user location
        protected LocationManager locationManager;
        protected LocationListener locationListener;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Looper.prepare();
              locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
              locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 1, locationListener);

              this.publishProgress(l);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Location... values) {

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        //this method is never executed i dont know why...?
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if (location != null){
                latLocation = location.getLatitude(); 
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " Your latLocation :" + latLocation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Log.d("Your Location", ""+latLocation);
            }
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {


        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


      }


}
```

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: the onLocationChanged method is never invoked.

Answer (score 2):

I've just implemented such `AsyncTask`:

```
class GetPositionTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Location> implements LocationListener
{
    final long TWO_MINUTES = 2*60*1000;
    private Location location;
    private LocationManager lm;

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        // Configure location manager - I'm using just the network provider in this example
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, this);
        nearProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    protected Location doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        // Try to use the last known position
        Location lastLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        // If it's too old, get a new one by location manager
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastLocation.getTime() > TWO_MINUTES)
        {
            while (location == null)
                try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (Exception ex) {}

            return location;
        }

        return lastLocation;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Location location)
    {
        nearProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.removeUpdates(this);

        // HERE USE THE LOCATION
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation)
    {
        location = newLocation;
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read and tried, you cannot use a looper (which is needed by the locationlistener), inside an ASyncTask.  [Click Here](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg62797.html)

> Actually it mean the two threading models are not compatible, so you can't
>   use these together.  Looper expects to to own the thread that you associate
>   it with, while AsyncTask owns the thread it creates for you to run in the
>   background.  They thus conflict with each other, and can't be used together.

Dianne Hackborn suggested using a HandlerThread, but I succeeded in getting mine to work inside of an IntentService.   I will admit that my code is still a bit of a hack.